# How to do something when entering a div using the keyboard tab key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I 'do something' with jQuery when entering a div using the keyboard tab key? For example, when a user navigates using the keyboard tab button, and they enter the 'Inside' div in the example below, the console log doesn't fire until the tab button is pressed a second time:

```js
$('.inside').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    console.log('Inside');
  }
});
```

```css
.inside {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outside {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="outside text-center">
    <a href="">Outside Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inside text-center">
    <a href="">Inside Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so use a focus event on the anchor

Comment: I wish I could, however, this will be part of a component and can't be applied to a specific anchor.

Comment: Have you tried `keyup`?

Comment: do you need this to be triggered with the mouse?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev - No. This is an accessibility requirement we've been asked to implement. When someone enters the carousel using their mouse, the focus needs to be on the first link of whatever slide is the active (visible) slide.

Comment: @linnse added blue bg to a focused link to make it more obvious

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$('.inside').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    console.log('Inside');
  }
});
```

Basically, when using 'keydown', the listener that triggers your function waits for the tab button to be pressed after the focus entered the .inside div. So, if you need the function to be triggered as soon as the focus moves to .inside div, then you can just check if tab button goes 'up' inside the .inside div

UPD: if you need it to be triggered only for the first link, then something like this should work (the code a bit messy but it does what you need)

```
$('.inside').on('keyup', function(e) {
  const el = document.querySelector('.inside>:first-child');
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    if (el === document.activeElement) {
      console.log('Inside');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. This is close to what we need, but we only need it to fire when entering the div. This solution fires every time the tab button is pressed within the 'Inside' div. It should only fire upon entering the div.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the `focus` event on the DIV's links and if the previous focused element is outside of the DIV, react to the event. Works with any TAB navigation direction and the mouse also.

```js
$('.inside a').on('focus', function(e) {
  if($(e.originalEvent.relatedTarget).parents('.inside').length){
    // focus is moved inside the div, so ignore
    return;
  }
  console.log('Inside');
  
});
```

```css
:focus{
background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="outside text-center">
  <a href="#">Outside Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Outside Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Outside Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Outside Link 4</a>
</div>
<div class="inside text-center">
  <a href="#">Inside Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Inside Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Inside Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Inside Link 4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. This is close, but our persnickety team wants the focus to be on the first link when entering the div and not the container itself.

Comment: @linnse fixed, enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `keyup` event instead.

Be aware that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is **deprecated**. It is better to use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

In the example below, `event.currentTarget` is always the `div.inside` element. So we can always query down to the `:first-child` and compare it to the `event.target`.

```js
$('.inside').on('keyup', function({ currentTarget, key, target }) {
  if (
    key === 'Tab' &&
    $(target).get(0) === $(currentTarget).find('a:first-child').get(0)
  ) {
    console.log('Inside');
  }
});
```

```css
.inside {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outside {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="outside text-center">
    <a href="">Outside Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Outside Link 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inside text-center">
    <a href="">Inside Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Inside Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to working in my environment. How can I target the first-child if it's not a direct descendent?

Comment: @linnse you mean the first `<a>` element? I updated the response to query on `a:first-child`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When a user tabs into the active slide in our carousel, focus needs to be on the first <a> element, if there is an <a> element. There are usually 0, 1 or 2 <a> elements in a slide.

Comment: @linnse if the response below worked out, feel free to acknowledge it.

Comment: I've been digging through this portion of the code and can't seem to wrap my head around it. Can you explain what it does? It's not working for me when I implement in my component. 
$(target).get(0) === $(currentTarget).find('a:first-child').get(0)

Comment: @linnse I destructured `key`, `target`, and `currentTarget` off of the incoming `event` object param (the first one). If you have a signature of `e` or `event`, just call `$(e.target)` and `$(e.currentTarget)`